# Why are some colors shown as one in some display programs?

Tags: color, gimp, color-spaces

I am very confused about this png. The colours look different on different programs. There are two types of programs:

- the ones who display it correctly with many different shades of colours in its view. For example Gimp (from which I exported the image) or my desktop browser (firefox)
- the ones who show different shades of a colour as one. For example GNOME image viewer or my mobile browser (android chrome)

For me most notably is that the second kind of programs make the orange line above the red footer simply appear as a red line, so that the footer becomes one big block of red.

I first thought that I have some error in my settings in GIMP and that I am not exporting the image correctly. But when I do a screenshot directly from GIMP the screenshot has the same issues (some programs group together colours). It also doesn't matter if I export the image to jpg, still the same issues.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the image how it should look like
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

[image: Image with discernable orange line on the footer]

And Here how it looks like on some programs

[image: Image where the footer is shown as one red colour]

Answer (score 1):

Different apps & browsers interpret colour profiles embedded in images in different ways.

Your first image is an 'untagged' RGB image - ie, it has no definitive information as to which colour space it should occupy. Most apps would consider that with no other information, it should be considered as an sRGB image, as that's the internet default.

Applying an sRGB profile to it gives an image like your first. Using any profile-aware app to then embed that back into the image & it should now be properly portable.
Try this - which is image 1 with an sRGB profile added [without doing any conversion, simply adding it to the unaltered image]

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
Some applications ignore the profile & always assume sRGB, some ignore only if there is no profile. The result is, frankly, a mess. Chrome & Firefox both have what I could only call 'awkward' defaults. They can be tweaked by the user into a more generally-presentable form. I honestly don't know why they chose these defaults.

See this from our sister site Photography.SE [Pictures uploaded to Facebook display wrong colors, but only in Firefox](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/124357/57929) for how to fix this on Firefox.

I found directions for Chrome & other indicators for this profiling behaviour on BenQ - [Color Management for Your Web Browsers](https://www.benq.eu/en-uk/knowledge-center/knowledge/web-browsers-color-management.html) which I haven't tested. I'm on Mac, Safari, which simply doesn't suffer from this issue at all on a fully-calibrated system.

BTW, I cannot tell what the second image has been misinterpreted as, but it now has a valid sRGB profile embedded - so any reverse-engineering starts by assuming that the sRGB profile is"correct".

Comment: Just a little note, to assign a colour profile in GIMP without converting, click *Image > Color Management > Assign Color Profile* and choose "sRGB IEC61966-2.1".

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I still cannot solve my issue. Apparently I don't know enough. I'm going to ask the same question in a forum as I think I need more direct feedback. If I could resolve the issue and it was the problem you described Teetsujin, I'm going to accept it.